# Does a non-simple perfect group always have a maximal subgroup whose derived subgroup has nontrivial core?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G \neq 1$ be a finite perfect group which is not simple.
Is it true that $G$ necessarily has a maximal subgroup whose derived subgroup
has nontrivial core in $G$?

*Remark 1:* This holds for all such $G$ of order less than 100000.

*Remark 2:* In case the answer is negative, I would mainly be interested
in a counterexample with nontrivial Frattini subgroup.

Comment: There are not that many perfect groups of order less than $100000$.

Comment: @markvs More precisely, there are 444 perfect groups of order less than 100000. Of these, 31 are simple and 1 is trivial -- so in this range of orders, there are 412 nontrivial perfect groups which are not simple.

Comment: @StefanKohl: For most of these groups the statement is obvious (I assume the "core" means normal core).

Comment: @markvs I checked that the assertion is true for all non-simple perfect groups of order less than 1000000.

Comment: There are no counterexamples among quasisimple groups. If $G$ is quasisimple, let $p$ be a prime divisor of $Z(G)$, and $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then by a transfer result, $P\cap Z(G)\le[P,P]$. Any maximal subgroup $M$ containing $P$ will then satisfy $P\cap Z(G)\le[M,M]$.

Comment: All you need for my comment is that $Z(G)\ne 1$.

Comment: Does there exist a finite simple group $S$, a field of prime order $K$ and a nontrivial irreducible $KS$-module $V$ such that for every proper subgroup $M$ of $S$ one has $V^M\neq 0$? (if so, $S\ltimes V$ is an example for the question). Even the answer for $K=\mathbf{C}$ would be of interest (and probably enough), and could be checked with a computer for groups $S$  for which maximal subgroups are known and character tables are known for $S$ and its maximal subgroups (I have only checked $|S|=60$: there's no $V$ then).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the title question is 'No.' Following YCor's comment, an example is furnished by $S=J_1$, the smallest Janko sporadic group, and its complex irreducible character $\chi$ of degree 76 (in Atlas notation, 76a). I have checked by hand (hopefully correctly), using the Atlas, that $(\chi\downarrow M,1_M)>0$ for all maximal subgroups $M$ of $J_1$. For any prime $p$ not dividing $|J_1|=2^3.3.5.7.11.19$, let $N_p$ be an $F_pS$-module affording the mod-$p$ reduction of $\chi$. Then, as YCor points out, the semidirect product $N_pS$ has the property that for every maximal subgroup $H\le N_pS$, $[H,H]$ does not contain $N_p$.

However, this example has trivial Frattini subgroup.

Comment: If the character is not defined over $\mathbf{Q}$, the set of possible $p$ might be smaller than a subset of finite complement of the set of primes. However it should be a set of positive density in any case (by Chebotarev).

Comment: @YCor: Good point, but the character is in fact rational-valued, and Schur indices are trivial over finite fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your counterexample! 
Can you tell whether the answer to the question would get positive if one replaces
*non-simple perfect group* by *non-simple minimal non-solvable group*?

Comment: Well, the top composition factor would be one of Thompson's $N$-groups, and their character tables are known, so if there's a similar counterexample, one could in principle find it.